# Roll back AWS stack creation when a bash script fails

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a cloud formation template which creates a stack. The stack creates different instances, instance 1 and instance 2. During the creation of instance 1 a bash script is run. I need the stack creation to roll back when the exit code of this bash script is 1. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Put `set -euo pipefail` at the top of your script under the `#!/bin/bash` line. That'll cause the script to return a failed status if your command fails, which should result in a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CFN Signal to send signal to Cloudformation upon failure at userdata

Take a look at this example

https://cumulus-ds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cf_examples.html